# Tables of contents with hyperlink in Ods pdf

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a table of contents with hyperlink in Ods pdf.My requirements are I want a table of contents with page no as well as hyperlink also.
I have try two methods.

1. I have created table of contents with datalines in which I have used ods pdf anchor to create hyperlink in pdf report but I am not getting page no.
2. I have used ods proclabel to create table of contents in that I am getting page no but not getting hyperlink

Comment: have tried TOC in Ods RTF it's working and I am getting page no also but to view that TOC everytime i have to press Alt+F9 is this any other way that I can view that TOC without pressing any key.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried, and perhaps someone can help you improve it.

Comment: Which version of SAS are you using ? You can use `PROC SETINIT;RUN;` to see the version in the log window.

Comment: I am using SAS 9.2

Comment: @user667489 I need a method to create a TOC with hyperlink in pdf that's it

Comment: @Richard I am using SAS eg 4.3 having SAS 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of 2). ODS PDF CONTENTS creates a TOC with entries that are the bookmark items, however none of the items or page numbers are hyperlinks.  I don't think there is an ODS feature that lets you specify that PDF TOC entries should also be hyperlinks.

```
ods _all_ close;

ods pdf 
  file="%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))\sample-%sysfunc(monotonic()).pdf"
  contents=yes  %* specify TOC be generated, can also specify with CONTENTS/NOCONTENTS;
;

ods proclabel "SASHELP.CLASS listing"; * Bookmark level 1;
title "SASHELP.CLASS";

options nodate nonumber;

proc print noobs data=sashelp.class
  contents='' %* option as empty-string removes bookmark level 2;
;
run;

ods proclabel "SASHELP gender counts";
title "Gender frequency";

proc sgplot data=sashelp.class 
  description="Simple bar chart" %* option sets bookmark level 2;
;
  vbar sex ; 
run;

ods pdf close;
```